# how could I solve this equation, any idea?

Tags: imacros

I have the code for imacros
I would like to receive the result.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=TYPE:text&&NAME:firstNumber&&VALUE:8
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=TYPE:text&&NAME:secondNumber&&VALUE:9


SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=TYPE:text&&NAME:firstNumber&&VALUE:8 EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=TYPE:text&&NAME:secondNumber&&VALUE:9 EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var a=\"{{!VAR1}}\"; var b=\"{{!VAR2}}\"; var z = (((a + b))); z") 
PROMPT {{!VAR3}}
```

I already tried this code, and even result
[click to see the result of imcros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcdt3.png)

any idea how I can solve.

Comment: What language is that? Doesn't seem to resemble javascript...

Comment: sorry bro, this language and iimacro
I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

All what you need is to parse the variable to int before plus action.

```
var a = parseInt( "{{!VAR1}}" );
var b = parseInt( "{{!VAR2}}" );
var z = a + b;
z;
```

So for your source code you just need to do:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=TYPE:text&&NAME:firstNumber&&VALUE:8
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=TYPE:text&&NAME:secondNumber&&VALUE:9

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=TYPE:text&&NAME:firstNumber&&VALUE:8 EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=TYPE:text&&NAME:secondNumber&&VALUE:9 EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var a = parseInt( "{{!VAR1}}" );var b = parseInt( "{{!VAR2}}" );var z = a + b;z") 
PROMPT {{!VAR3}}
```

Comment: as it would be in the language of imacro, I'm starting to study shortly.

Comment: @gustavoalves there is it...
The all code is "imacro" but the code part of js is as is in...
I will edit the answer for full solution.

Comment: @gustavoalves I was edit the answer with your source code.